# convert relative URLs to absolute URLs with PHP for a complete webpage

Tags: php, simplexml

I am using PHP to read a HTML file:

```
$w = file_get_contents('http://localhost/site1/theme/default/about.html');
```

The PHP code is run from `http://localhost/site1/`. I have used `simplexml` to find things like images so `src="images/image1.png"` and change it to `http://localhost/site1/theme/default/about/images/image1.png`.
This works but how would I change things like

```
background-image: url("../images/World1.png");
```

and

```
href="../../stylesheet.css"
```

to absolute paths? I looked at `url_to_absolute.php` but couldn't get it to
do what I need.